Remove all nested XML tags
I am trying to remove all "nested tags of same type". For every XML element, if you find another subelement in its subtree that has same name, remove its tag (keep its contents). In another words, transform <a>...<a>...</a>...</a> into <a>.........</a>.
I created a very nice and simple piece of code using functions iter and strip_tags from the lxml package:
import lxml.etree

root = lxml.etree.parse('book.txt')

for element in root.iter():
    lxml.etree.strip_tags(element, element.tag)

print(lxml.etree.tostring(root).decode())

I used this input file:
<book>
    <b><title>My <b>First</b> Book</title></b>
    <i>Introduction <i><i>To</i></i> LXML</i>
    <name><a>Author: <a>James</a></a></name>
</book>

and I got this output:
<book>
    <b><title>My First Book</title></b>
    <i>Introduction To LXML</i>
    <name><a>Author: <a>James</a></a></name>
</book>

As you can see, it removed almost all the nested tags except one: <a>Author: <a>James</a></a>. What is wrong with the code? How can I fix it?

Just a sanity question: Does etree.iter() support mutating the tree during traversal?

what if you will have element nested in already nested element? It may need to use recursion.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

when I run print( element.tag ) in for-loop then I don't show name and a. Probably there is similar problem like with removing elements from list when you iterate list.

It is not safe to modify the XML tree while iterating over it. Instead, iterate over a list of all elements.
import lxml.etree

root = lxml.etree.parse('book.txt')

all_elements = list(root.iter())

for element in all_elements:
    lxml.etree.strip_tags(element, element.tag)
    
print(lxml.etree.tostring(root).decode())

Output:
<book>
    <b><title>My First Book</title></b>
    <i>Introduction To LXML</i>
    <name><a>Author: James</a></name>
</book>


That is so clever and elegant! Of course it may seem obvious to those who already know the trick. I will remember to keep the "iteration plan" safe and aside before I start modifying. Thank you.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3346696/407651

In XSLT it's
<xsl:template match="*[node-name() = ancestor::*/node-name()]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

